# Is it possible to create a Custom UICollectionViewCell which looks like a table for data entry?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, user-interface

I am relatively new to iOS development in general, what I would like to know is:

Is it possible to create some form of cell like [this diagram image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhdRz.png)?

On the image, there is an 'Add' button at the bottom, when the user clicks this I would like the cell to add another row. So initially it starts with just one row and then adds more from user preference.

Comment: have you tried googling uitableview tutorial??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by using [UITableView](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview). You can customize a [UITableViewCell](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewcell) (each row with different data) to look like this:

[image]

I hope that you can imagine how the whole tableView should looks like.

---

**ALSO**: assuming that you checked how to work with tableviews and knowing how you should conform to [UITableViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdelegate),

[image]

you could add the section above as a [tableView(_:viewForHeaderInSection:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614901-tableview).

[image]

and this one as a [tableView(_:viewForFooterInSection:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614946-tableview).

Hope this helped.